# how to use log4j to write a file inside my project directory?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, log4j

I have a log4j properties file which is creating a file inside my tomcat>bin folder but instead can it write the log file to my project's root dir? **webapps>test>*_*__**?

Here is my log4j properties file contents.

```
#define the console appender
log4j.appender.consoleAppender = org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender

# now define the layout for the appender
log4j.appender.consoleAppender.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.consoleAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=%t %-5p %c{3} - %m%n

log4j.appender.rollingFile=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.rollingFile.File=/test/a.log
log4j.appender.rollingFile.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.rollingFile.MaxBackupIndex=2
log4j.appender.rollingFile.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.rollingFile.layout.ConversionPattern=%p %t %c - %m%n

# now map our console appender as a root logger, means all log messages will go to this appender
#for console printing
#log4j.rootLogger = DEBUG, consoleAppender   

#for file printing
log4j.rootLogger = DEBUG, rollingFile
```

Comment: Usually I just hard code the location. I think relative path is a bad idea in web apps which your environment may change according to the container.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try replacing this:

```
log4j.appender.rollingFile.File=/test/a.log
```

with this:

```
log4j.appender.rollingFile.File=../webapps/test/a.log
```

---

Note (by Stephen C) - the "../" means this solution depends on whether or not the Tomcat launch mechanism you use makes $CATALINA_HOME the current directory before the JVM that hosts Tomcat.  Some do, and some don't.

Comment: doesn't "../webapps/" rely on current directory when the JVM is launched?

Comment: @Stephen: Yes. But when you are using TOMCAT it will be bin folder of tomcat so as long as OP is using TOMCAT its correct.

Comment: You should be more specific than "using tomcat correctly".  Precisely what do you mean by that?

Comment: @StephenC I guess you mean I should answer in more general way and not just tomcat specific, like yours in this question. In that case I also feel that and upvoted your answer for it, I haven't updated my answer because it might look like correcting your mistakes from other's answer.

Comment: No.  I mean that you should say what you mean by *"But when you are using TOMCAT it will be bin folder of tomcat so as long as OP is using TOMCAT its correct."*.  Clearly, you have a particular mental model of what "using tomcat correctly" is.  Like launching tomcat in a particular way.  I'm simply suggesting that you spell it out ... so that people reading the accepted answer KNOW what they need to do in order to make your solution work.

Comment: @StephenC Oh.. I meant when someone run tomcat from it's stratup scripts inside tomcat's bin folder, this solution will work. I hope you get it now.

Comment: If that's what you mean, then I think you are wrong for Unix/Linux.  I've read (for example) the Tomcat 7.0.14 shell scripts carefully, and I cannot see where they change the current directory.  And this is not **documented** behaviour. (Some of the Windows BAT files do ... so maybe that's where you got this notion from.)

Comment: @StephenC I tried Tomcat 6 on Linux and it worked there if you start tomcat from it's bin directory. I mean going into bin and starting it. And I monitor if you start tomcat from some other place than bin then it won't work, as the current directory doesn't resolved the path. So I guess my solution works for some scenarios but is not the perfect one, should I remove it?

Comment: (Yes ... that's what I was getting at ...)  I think there should just be a note to say that your solution works in situation X but not Y.  I'll do it for you ...

Answer (score 8):

The log4j configurations understand `"${catalina.home}"`, so ...

```
 log4j.appender.rollingFile.File=${catalina.home}/webapps/test/a.log
```

However, I don't think it is a good idea to put logs into the `webapps` tree because they are liable to be blown away if your webapp is redeployed.

Put them in `${catalina.home}/logs` instead.

Or better still, put them in the distro-specific *conventional* place to put application logfiles; e.g. "/var/spool/..." or "/var/log/...".

Putting logfiles in standard places means there are less places for someone else (e.g. the guy who is the backup sysadmin when you are on holiday) to investigate if the file system fills up with old logfiles.

Comment: Thanks, I was just curious, as there are other projects too where I was saving the logs and my bin folder was filled with full of logs. So I decided to go for this. Thanks anyways. Harry answered my question first